# Feature engineering in marketing analytics in python

Tags: python, feature-engineering

Feature Engineering for marketing analytics in Python

I have a data with variables `offer_id` (e.g. 1,2,5,10....) and `product_id` (e.g. 6178,4184,5124,...). An `offer_id` can be applicable to multiple `product_id`.

How can I make a separate variable for each product_id such that if a particular `offer_id` is applicable on it then `product_id` variable get a value 1 otherwise it get a value 0.

The separate variables for each product_id must have either 0 or 1 as value. A value of 0 to indicate an `offer_id` is not applicable and a value of 1 to indicate that the corresponding `offer_id` is applicable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you could create new columns by mapping simple functions for each offer type to check for the value in the offer_id column. (if value == 5 return 1, else return 0 etc.).

Similarly, you could use the [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to achieve the same thing. I.e. create new columns by doing conditional checks of the offer_id column.

eg: `df['is_5'] = np.where(df.offer_id == 5, 1, 0)`

(i.e. if offer_id == 5, return 1 else return 0).